# LISTAGG Partition for Webi

Tags: webi

I would like to do something similar to oracle LISTAGG in Webi. Below are my Queries.

Query 1

```
Id      M1  ; columns
1       10
2       20
3       30
4       40
5       50
```

Query 2

```
Id      D1  ; column
1       A11
1       A12
1       A13
2       A21
2       A22
2       A23
2       A24
3       A31
```

wanted outcome by merging Query 1 and Query 2 By Id

```
Id      M1      New Column
1       10      A11;A12;A13
2       20      A21;A22;A23;A24
3       30      A31
4       40
5       50
```

I can get to the point below. Then, use NoFilter to keep values intact when applying a filter. However, the column F2 has the values "#MULTIVALUE". I can get NoFilter to work with one query. But, with two queries like this, NoFilter doesn't work. Any suggestion to address the issue.

```
Id      M1      F1 (Measure)            F2
1       10      A11;A12;A13            =NoFilter([F1]) 
1       10      A11;A12;A13
1       10      A11;A12;A13
2       20      A21;A22;A23;A24
2       20      A21;A22;A23;A24
2       20      A21;A22;A23;A24
2       20      A21;A22;A23;A24
3       30      A31
4       40
5       50
```

I wonder if anyone could show me how to achieve this.

Many thanks for your help,

Andre

Comment: Check out this blog [post](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/08/15/string-aggregation-on-webi-report-level/). I have tried to get it to work, but haven't been able to yet. Maybe you can get it.

Comment: Thanks Isaac for your tip. I can get it work with one query, But, with two queries and merging, I failed at the last hurdle. NoFilter function seems not work with merging + "Allow duplicates row aggregation". The function returns "#MULTIVALUE". You have any suggestion to address the issue. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you create the query like you want in Oracle using LISTAGG and drop it into WebI with free-hand SQL?

Comment: OK. Many thanks for your help.